# Why `keyof` doesn’t contribute to the reference of the original type? Does it lose track of the original symbol by design?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering why renaming a property (in my IDE [VSCode] and in the TypeScript playground) in a type doesn't rename it in a string literal assigned to a `keyof` of that type.

References of this sort seem to come from TypeScript, rather than (just) from the IDE implementation, so I think it relates to how TypeScript keeps track of references internally.

([This TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44643) is very similar, supporting the idea that references like this are part of TypeScript.)

Suppose I start with this code:

```ts
type T1 = { a: true; b: true }
type T2 = { [T in keyof T1]: boolean }
type T3 = keyof T1

let t1: T1 = { a: true, b: true }
let t2: T2 = { a: true, b: true }
let t3: T3 = "a"
```

Then I highlight the `a` in `T1` and do a rename operation in my IDE/ts playground, changing `a` to `x`. This is the resulting code:

```ts
type T1 = { x: true; b: true }
type T2 = { [T in keyof T1]: boolean }
type T3 = keyof T1

let t1: T1 = { x: true, b: true }
let t2: T2 = { x: true, b: true }
let t3: T3 = "a"
```

Notice how `a` changed to `x` in the type, and also in the object literals assigned to `t1` and `t2`, but the string literal assigned to `t3` *didn't* change from `"a"` to `"x"`.

Mapped types also keep track. If I have:

```ts
type Merge<First extends object, Second extends object> = {
  [Token in keyof ({
    [K in keyof First]: First[K]
  } & {
    [K in keyof Second]: Second[K]
  })]: boolean
}
```

and then have this:

```ts
type M1 = { a: true; b: true }
type M2 = { b: true; c: true }
type M3 = Merge<M1, M2>
let m3: M3 = { a: true, b: true, c: true }
```

Renaming `a` to `x` in the IDE changes that to:

```ts
type M1 = { x: true; b: true }
type M2 = { b: true; c: true }
type M3 = Merge<M1, M2>
let m3: M3 = { x: true, b: true, c: true }
```

Notice how `a` was changed to `x` even in the object literal for `M3`.

Is this a language limitation? (Or even a bug?) Or this is how types should work in general?

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHEEsDcFMDsCwAoALgTwA61AFQIygC8oA3qAIYBcoqATgK6wDcoARjfU6AL4obY8AJmJlQAbVyhI8UAGtY6APYAzPPgC6NNkqUAbWBVl80WHLgDMohcrUEUKEKABKCCgFscAAwpfpsrwI-JTpQL1R8YNDwoT9UJTCADy8UA1RafBoCUXJqWkZYABp2TgLeUCcAWkqAPjFE0qZijnzuEzTaISyRElzGopLWnB4KsGq68gah5v7eVNh01AssqxIAIgo10dAAOQSAYwALIwBzHCoACkcwAEEVVFhQujdPWjN1HNAprhZBn7nkPx3gBZR5nAA8ADFIHQAM7pWCJB7wAAmsNASjYACtYPtUMUAMq4pSo0CI5FojHY3GoOq9FCgCS4JQKWQyeSKVSgC6kBmMiQAaX8HNsoGhcNQWjFMPh4gFGj5IwAZGQ%20Yy5cKbFyifsSSipTq9XKFchGTwAJRSnT6QxIZAma4uF7eXygWpJFKmQTAwi9Sj9Vgtf4jKruyYBv5lEwCHDAnpiIMFVj7WbRkGrUCgugQn3FOM1ebpdzLTMZvrTSNNUApoblUMTL4RxNtBzIJyueAebxsPzurzJIGCSG%20sR5H6B1Pbcb1Jupwc4SHx8jN3414PbPbV47wM6gS7zsUZrMQ4fFRcF5AdFQlyFl-0VlfFNdRqdh%208-YrfApP1NAA)

Comment: Do you mind if I do an edit to the question that I think will make it much clearer? You can always roll it back. :-)

Comment: Done. Hopefully that will help you get an answer. :-)

Comment: Wow! That is an amazing edit! Thank you very much!!! Makes it so clear! I am really curious how this symbol tracking works under the hood

Comment: Great additional edit, that first paragraph (of mine) was a mess, you really fixed it up. :-)

Comment: And you really fixed up the question :)